# Multi threading visibility and Atomicity

Tags: java, multithreading

I was going through volatile keyword,reading about it,where I read that volatile keyword guarantee visibility not atomicity,now visibility is that changes made in one thread is immediately visible to the other thread,so why we need to use atomic Integer or atomic boolean..what's the need of it,can some one explain me with **one common example use of volatile ,and difference of visibility and atomicity**

Comment: Okay, so change is immedialty visible to a different thread. Say you have a counter you want to increase. That involves two steps: reading the current value, storing the increased value again. Those two steps shouldn't be interupted. That's what `AtomicInteger` do that `volatile` can't do.

Answer (score 5):

**Definitions**

An operation is *atomic* if any other thread either perceives it to have taken place completely, or not at all.

An operation is *visible* to another thread, it that thread perceives it to have taken place.

The classic example for usefulness of atomicity is an operation that deposits money into a bank account:

```
synchronized void deposit(int dollars) {
    balance = balance + dollars;
}
```

If that operation were not atomic, two threads (T1 and T2) that want to deposit money to the same account at the same time could execute as follows

```
T1 reads balance and adds dollars
T2 reads balance and adds dollars
T1 writes the result to balance
T2 writes the result to balance
```

which is incorrect, as the money deposited by T1 does not contribute to the balance.

The classic example for usefulness of visibility is passing information from one thread to another. For instance, the user interface thread might pass a command to a background thread.

**Meaning of volatile**

volatile makes writing to (or reading from) a variable atomic, even if they are of type `long` or `double`.

Writing to a volatile variable is visible to all threads subsequently reading from that variable.

That is, we can use volatile to pass information to another thread, for instance:

```
volatile boolean shouldBeRunning = true;

void stop() { // invoked by T1
    shouldBeRunning = false;
}

void run() { // invoked by T2
    while (shouldBeRunning) {
        doWork();
    }
}
```

**Advantage of AtomicBoolean**

As we have seen above, we can make writing to (or reading from) a `boolean` atomic by declaring it `volatile`. However, if we want to make a larger operation such as

```
void pauseOrResume() {
    paused = !paused;
}
```

atomic, declaring `paused` volatile is not sufficient, as two threads T1 and T2 can execute pauseOrResume at the same time as follows:

```
T1 reads paused (false) and negates it (true)
T2 reads paused (false) and negates it (true)
T1 writes its result (true)
T2 writes its result (true)
```

With an atomic boolean, we can prevent this from happening:

```
void pauseOrResume() {
    boolean pausedBefore = paused.get();
    if (!paused.compareAndSet(pausedBefore, !pausedBefore)) {
        pauseOrResume();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Lets go through the two concepts separately.

**Visibility**

Changes to a variable are guaranteed to be visibile to all threads accessing the variable. Visibility prevents threads of caching local copies of the variable

**Atomicity**

Changes to a variavble are atomic, the happen all at once or not at all. There is no chance that a thread will see a variable before all operations are complete.

Example where visibility is required but atomicity is automatically guaranteed by the JLS:

```
private static volatile boolean run;

public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executorService.submit(new Worker());
    TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);
    run = false;
    executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
}

private static final class Worker implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (run) {
            try {
                //do some long running task
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                //oh well                    
            }
            System.out.println("Working really hard");
        }
    }

}
```

Here we use `run` as a `volatile boolean` flag. We require that the thread running the `Worker` sees changes to the value of the `boolean` but as assignemnt is already atomic we do not need to synchronise in any way.

Example where visibility is not sufficient, atomicity is also required:

```
private static volatile boolean run;
private static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    run = true;
    executorService.submit(new Decrementor());
    executorService.submit(new Incremetror());
    TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);
    run = false;
    executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
}

private static final class Incremetror implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (run) {
            while (counter.get() < 10) {
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    //oh well
                }
                System.out.println(counter.incrementAndGet());
            }
        }
    }

}

private static final class Decrementor implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (run) {
            while (counter.get() >= 10) {
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    //oh well
                }
                System.out.println(counter.decrementAndGet());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This slightly contrived example shows two threads reading a setting a counter variable. Threads carry out some long running task then set the counter. Once the first thread takes the counter to 10 then the second thread begins to decrement it. The result is that the counter usually switches between 9 and 10, but there could be a situation where the counter in decremented all the way by the second thread due to thread scheduling.

The example uses a busy wait to emphasise the need for atomicity. This should never be used in practice.

The salient point is that `i++` **is not atomic**. It involved a read, an assignment and then a write. Here is visibility of the variable is not enough to gurarantee that the *correct* value would be seen. Another thread could see the variable in between any of the above operations.

Here you could use a `synchroized` block, but that is very expensive. This is where the Java `AtomicXXX` constructs come in.

Answer (score 0):

`AtomicInterger` a other `Atomic...` classes guarantee atomicity. I.e. its  guarantee  that variable can not be changed by 2 or more threads simultaneously, for example this code is not thread safe, it have `race condition` problem:

```
private volatile int a;

private void myMethod() {
   a++;
}
```

Because thread A can read value of `a` and it will be 0, then thread B read value of `a` - it also equals to 0. But then both threads increments this read value and it will remain value `1`, but should be `2`.

I.e. Atomicity  guarantee  that `read-change-write` operations will be done correctly, while `volatil` guarantee   only that "read" operations will be done correctly.